# change font size and circle the pointers

Tags: image

**MWE**

```
{i1, i2} = 
 Import@# & /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/laZeT.png", 
"https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAHyF.png"};
(*Binarize the image and delete speckles to get clear edge detections*)
images = {DeleteSmallComponents@Binarize[i1, .2], 
DeleteSmallComponents@Binarize[i2, .2]};
(*match corresponding points in both images*)
Print[Style[
  "Find corresponding points in the two images that are similar ", 
  FontWeight -> "Bold", FontColor -> Blue]]
matches = ImageCorrespondingPoints[images[[1]], images[[2]]]
Print[Style["Find the resulting shift ", FontWeight -> "Bold", 
FontColor -> Blue]]
ImgShiftCoord = {Flatten[matches[[1]]][[1]] - 
Flatten[matches[[2]]][[1]], 
Flatten[matches[[1]]][[2]] - Flatten[matches[[2]]][[2]]}
 (*map the matching points in both images and calculate the pixel \
shifts*)
Print[Style["Show the outstanding matching region of interest ", 
FontWeight -> "Bold", FontColor -> Blue]]
MapThread[
 Show[#1, Graphics[{Red, 
   MapIndexed[Inset[#2[[1]], #1] &, #2]}]] &, {images, matches}]
```

**Plot:**
[image: 1]

---

How can I change the font size of those markers {1,2,3} and also circle them so that I can show it in my presentation clearly as to what I am talking about ? The font sizes are so small and hard to see of there are many.

Comment: As a guide rule, try to post MWEs (Minimal Working Examples) related to your problem and showing it as clearly as possible. Any code non-related to your current problem is noise and discourage potential answerers

Comment: Have added the link to import the pics so anyone can run the code without any problem. I just want to increase those markers font size and encircle them so that when I export as image, I can add it to my thesis presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the font size and circle the numbers... replace the final statement with:

```
MapThread[Show[#1, Graphics[{FontSize -> 30, Red, 
 MapIndexed[{Circle[#1, 20], Inset[#2[[1]], #1]} &, #2]}]] &, {images, matches}]
```

[image]